# How to make an AS3 Flash video player?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, video-streaming

I would like to make a Flash video player that takes a URL as an attribute when you embed it and loads the video based upon that attribute.  All I need for the moment is a play/pause button.  How can I do this is AS3?  It needs to be able to play F4V files.

If it's simple to make other features, like full screen, showing how much of the video has been loaded on the timeline, or being able to click at any point in the timeline yo jump to that point in the video, please tell how!

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you really want to keep things simple, why make your own? You could just use existing customizable solutions, like FlowPlayer for example: [link](http://flowplayer.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making your own from scratch is inventing the wheel. if your doing it as a side project, that's fine but there isn't enough scrolling on this page in order to explain how to build you own player. You honestly best to google it.
A good source to get started is http://www.gotoandlearn.com/ and have a look at Lee Brimlows tutorials.

*If you're looking at building a player of your own - also consider using the new [StageVideo](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stagevideo.html) API as this will soon be standard for flash video.

---

There are many freebies out there to assist you in getting a video player made.

- http://flowplayer.org/ - popular, but
  charges for the good stuff.
- http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/
  this is JWplayer and you may have seen it in many places.
- http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/lightweight-flv-player-component-toobplayer/
  easy to use but is AS2

But I recommend http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/
This has been strongly developed within the towers of Adobe and theres nothing you cannot do with it. It's AS3 and free of charge. You can see examples of this on Adobes' Dev Net or Brimlows blog.

I use it myself and it includes many examples, embed code, documentation and feature plugins such as youtube and adverts.

Comment: the link is dead - anyone knows where stuff went?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [OSMF](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/osmf/Open+Source+Media+Framework), it will help you a lot.